# Switching from require to import for d3 v4 modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, webpack, es6-modules

I have a code being compiled/bundeled with webpack.  I've been using nodejs & require statements to bundle in my d3 components as such.

```
let d3 = Object.assign({}, require('d3-selection'), require('d3-timer'));
```

How do you do the equivalent using es6 import statements?

I can import a single module like so `import* as d3 from'd3-selection';` won't repeating it for d3-timer `import* as d3 from'd3-timer';` cause problems (overwrite the previous d3 module instance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import both the modules in differnt name and perform object assign

```
import * as d3Selection from'd3-selection';
import * as d3Timer from'd3-timer';
const d3 = Object.assign({}, d3Selection, d3Timer);
```